# Redirecting http to https in Google Cloud

Tags: .htaccess, google-compute-engine

I have setup a load balancer which accepts https connections from users. The compute engines are then connected to load balancer using http connection.

I have written the following .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now, the problem is, the compute engine is always connected via http link (to the load balancer) and not https.

Thus, the .htaccess file always consider the connection to be http and not https even if the url starts with https. So, it goes in an infinite loop trying to send the user to https even when the url is https.

What should be done to redirect http to https in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check the X-Forwarded-Proto http header. It is set by the load balancer and will have the value http or https.

Comment: .htacces file would be like:RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Hey Lennert. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 8):

This took so long for me to find the answer to!  Thank you so much @Lennert!

```
    user@host-vm:/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs# head -4 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, this helped!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me as well for finding the code. Just a note its working for www. as well

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using `php`, I've been looking for a simple way to make my project redirect any page to `https` in Google Cloud, and I found a simple solution. All you have to do is to add this code at the top of your `php` page. It has to be at the top, the **F̲i̲r̲s̲t̲ L̲i̲n̲e̲** of code in your header:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
  header("Location: https://www.YOUR_SITE.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  die();
}
?>
```