# Why does my domain not redirect to https?

Tags: angular, ssl, google-cloud-platform, https

So I basically set up google managed certificates for my angular application using app-engine. I thought that after setting it up it would automatically redirect users to the https version. Am I supposed to make some redirect for this myself?

I just want people that go to my website to automatically be redirected to https. I can't really find any documentation if this is even supposed to happen from their side. Hopefully some more experienced people can enlighten me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201969/redirecting-http-to-https-in-google-cloud/38202272

Comment: [Use secure: always on app.yml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/application-security#https_requests)

Comment: Which Google App Engine (Standard or Flexible)? Edit your question and include your deployment file (app.yaml). GAE Standard supports redirection, but GAE Flexible requires that you implement redirection.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

Like TasosV mentioned, you can use the [“secure: always” line](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/application-security#https_requests) in the app.yaml to redirect automatically to HTTPS.